# How to find error rows in bulk insert?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, bulk-insert, ctas

MySQL 5.6: I'm experimenting with copying data from one table to another in different ways. The source table is on a remote server and has about 500,000 rows - I use the federated engine to connect. I first tried this:

```
mysql > create table tgt as select * from src;
```

This is very fast, takes only a few seconds, but it gives warnings:

```
...
| Warning | 1299 | Invalid TIMESTAMP value in column 'created_timestamp' at row 265975 |
| Warning | 1299 | Invalid TIMESTAMP value in column 'created_timestamp' at row 265976 |
...
64 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried instead to do it with a stored procedure, opening a cursor, fetching rows and inserting them, but it takes forever; I canceled after 10 min.

So, is there a way to locate the rows that cause the problem? I tried `select ... limit #first_row,#last_row;`, but it doesn't appear to work, and I'm not sure if it is entirely reliable any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the rows you want to see, you must do two things:

- change the way you create the table
- change the way you load data into the table

## Why Change the Way You Create the Table ???

When you did this

```
create table tgt as select * from src;
```

You create the `tgt` table without any indexes. You can verify this by running

```
show create table src \G
show create table tgt \G
```

and you will see `src` with its indexes and `tgt` without them.

Consequently, with no indexes around, the table load would be the fastest. If you at least had a primary key. you could navigate the table by some numeric `id` column.

So, to create table with the indexes in place, do this:

```
create table tgt like src;
```

You could then run

```
show create table src \G
show create table tgt \G
```

and see that they are the same in structure.

## Why Change the Way You Load Data into the Table ???

You could just start loading like this

```
insert into tgt select * from src;
```

When the load is done, you could run

```
SELECT * FROM tgt WHERE id = 265975;
SELECT * FROM tgt WHERE id = 265976;
```

You could get an glimpse at when the row looks like but the `created_timestamp` may not be populated. If it is populated correctly, then the problem is essentially solved.

## Another Way to See Which Row Without Loading Data

You could isolate which rows have an issue with the `created_timestamp` by doing something else

```
# mysqldump --skip-extended-insert mydb src > dumpfile.txt
# head -265976 dumpfile.txt | tail -2
```

This will show you the rows that would have been inserted.

This is all the help I can suggest since I do not know what the table structures are.

Comment: This is definitely helpful - I'll work on it and then come back and report how I solved the problem (and accpet your answer)